# DP-1 (DiplayPort) monitor not connecting in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: multiple-monitors, xorg, display

I m using Ubuntu 20.04 in optiplex 980 SFF, intel 965 chipset. I m using VGA port as primary display and want to connect secondary monitor through DisplayPort (DP-1).

when I run xrandr, it detects the the ports, please see output below -

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
mplusn@mplusn-OptiPlex-980:~$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1024 x 768, maximum 8192 x 8192
VGA-1 connected primary 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      60.00* 
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   848x480       60.00  
   640x480       59.94  
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
mplusn@mplusn-OptiPlex-980:~$ cvt 1680 1050
# 1680x1050 59.95 Hz (CVT 1.76MA) hsync: 65.29 kHz; pclk: 146.25 MHz


mplusn@mplusn-OptiPlex-980:~$ sudo xrandr --newmode "1680x1050_60.00" 146.25 1680 1784 1960 2240 1050 1053 1059 1089 -hsync +vsync

mplusn@mplusn-OptiPlex-980:~$ sudo xrandr --addmode DP-1 "1680x1050_60.00"
```

With the last step, I check display settings but I don't see Dp-1 monitor profile get added.

What am I missing here?

Comment: it looks like the DP monitor is disconnected entirely. It should show *something* when connected, even if it doesn't have the proper resolution or refresh rate. You will only see anything when the monitor is connected.

Comment: Thanks Esther you pointed me to right direction all this time I was troubleshooting from Xorg side but it turned out to be OSD settings, I needed to select from VGA to DP-1. Now I have FHD working on Ubuntu. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Changed input source on OSD  from VGA to DP-1 to fix the issue